# Is there a way to use my mouse or trackpad with my iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, trackpad

I'm looking for a way of using my trackpad to virtually tap things on my iPhone screen.  I realize this is a long shot, and iOS quite possibly makes this impossible, but I'm sure I'm not the only person who wants this, and this is the best place to ask.

I can use any bluetooth keyboard with my phone, and using Type2Phone I can direct a bluetooth signal from my laptop to my phone while it charges, and while I'm mainly using my laptop.  But then using the touch screen is very awkward.  I'd like to do the same thing with my trackpad that I do with my keyboard, so if I need to briefly use an iOS app while I'm working, I don't have to repeatedly take it off the stand every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can [pair a bluetooth keyboard](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202041) with an iOS device and use it, Apple does not support for pairing a bluetooth mouse or trackpad.

I did find that there is a third-party app for use on jailbroken iOS devices that allow you to do what you want. It provides an alternative Bluetooth Stack which provides the ability to use the trackpad or mouse. [See here](http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/btc-mouse-trackpad-cydia-tweak-ios/) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

Do not think it works as a standalone device. However, never tried it myself, but I guess that if one would attach a bluetooth keyboard with built in mousepath it could work.

Comment: I'm guessing from the downvotes (not mine!) that others have tried it and it won't work, but I will try that when I get home and have such a device handy.  Thanks for the idea!